# "Value of type 'CardCollectionViewCell' has no member 'flipBack'"

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUf6a.png)

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong to be getting this error !

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var model = CardModel ()
    var cardArray = [Card] ()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Call the getCards method of the card model
        cardArray = model.getCards()

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

    }

// MARK: - UICollection View Protocol Methods

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return cardArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // Get a CardCollectionViewCell object
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CardCell", for: indexPath) as! CardCollectionViewCell

        // Get the card that the CollectionView is trying to display
        let card = cardArray[indexPath.row]

        // Set that card for the cell
        cell.setCard(card)

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

       // Get the cell that the user selected
       let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CardCollectionViewCell

       // Get the card that the user selected
       let card = cardArray[indexPath.row]

        if card.isFlipped == false {

            // Flip the card
            cell.flip()

            // Set the status of the card
            card.isFlipped = true }

        else {
            // Flip the card back
            cell.flipBack()

            // Set the status of the card
            card.isFlipped = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the code of `CardCollectionViewCell`, do you have a `func flip(){}` and `func flipBack(){}`?

Comment: Please show the code for the `CardCollectionViewCell`. Without knowing what `flip()` does, my best guess is that you might want to call `cell.flip()` in the `else` statement, instead of `card.flipBack()`

Answer (score 0):

Your class `CardCollectionViewCell` does not contain definitions of the functions `flip()` and `flipBack()`